# Slimbox centering on whole page, not the window

Tags: javascript, positioning, slimbox

I was trying to integrate Slimbox into my web page, but couldn't get it to work properly. For some reason, the popup is centered on the whole page, not just its visible part. Here's an example of the situation: [here](http://ondra.cifka.com/_/slimbox/index.html).

I tested it in Firefox and Chrome on Linux and Slimboxes on other web pages look fine. Any idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I change the doctype from HTML 4.0 Transitional to XHTML 1.0 Transitional and it works like magic. Does anybody know why? There's something about having a XHTML doctype in Slimbox 1 readme, but they don't mention it in the readme to version 2.

Answer (score 2):

Also remember about `<!DOCTYPE html>` in HTML5 documents. 
In my case, this turned out to be important in Slimbox 2.05!

Comment: This seems like a good start of an answer, but a bit more detail would be quite helpful.

Comment: I agree with @user3303950 that this is an under-developed answer, but it worked to fix my problem, so +1